# Can't delete row in section

Tags: iphone, swift, core-data, ios8, xcode6.1

i've got a problem by deleting cells in a section.The tableViewController has three sections with various cells. If I try to delete one cell, the debugger will show:

> 2015-01-23 20:22:15.105 Grade - Zensurenverwaltung[23854:5674475] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318.16.14/UITableView.m:1566
>   2015-01-23 20:22:15.133 Grade - Zensurenverwaltung[23854:5674475] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (3) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (3), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 1 deleted).'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001008bef35 **exceptionPreprocess + 165
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001025adbb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001008bed9a +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
>       3   Foundation                          0x0000000100d565df -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 195
>       4   UIKit                               0x00000001013c98ff -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 10935
>       5   Grade - Zensurenverwaltung          0x00000001000fa0c2 _TFC26Grade___Zensurenverwaltung28TestTypesTableViewController9tableViewfS0_FTCSo11UITableView18commitEditingStyleOSC27UITableViewCellEditingStyle17forRowAtIndexPathCSo11NSIndexPath_T_ + 3618
>       6   Grade - Zensurenverwaltung          0x00000001000fa207 _TToFC26Grade___Zensurenverwaltung28TestTypesTableViewController9tableViewfS0_FTCSo11UITableView18commitEditingStyleOSC27UITableViewCellEditingStyle17forRowAtIndexPathCSo11NSIndexPath_T_ + 87
>       7   UIKit                               0x00000001013edcb4 -[UITableView animateDeletionOfRowWithCell:] + 130
>       8   UIKit                               0x00000001013ce125 __52-[UITableView _swipeActionButtonsForRowAtIndexPath:]_block_invoke + 72
>       9   UIKit                               0x00000001012f68be -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
>       10  UIKit                               0x00000001013fd410 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 467
>       11  UIKit                               0x00000001013fc7df -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 522
>       12  UIKit                               0x00000001016a3540 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 9487
>       13  UIKit                               0x000000010133bff6 -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1041
>       14  UIKit                               0x000000010133cc23 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 667
>       15  UIKit                               0x00000001013099b1 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246
>       16  UIKit                               0x0000000101316a7d _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 17370
>       17  UIKit                               0x00000001012f2103 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1961
>       18  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001007f4551 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
>       19  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001007ea41d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
>       20  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001007e9a54 __CFRunLoopRun + 868
>       21  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001007e9486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
>       22  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001052fd9f0 GSEventRunModal + 161
>       23  UIKit                               0x00000001012f5420 UIApplicationMain + 1282
>       24  Grade - Zensurenverwaltung          0x00000001001e164e top_level_code + 78
>       25  Grade - Zensurenverwaltung          0x00000001001e168a main + 42
>       26  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000102d87145 start + 1
>       27  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
>   )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

And i just don't get it...

Here is my code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    var indexes: NSMutableIndexSet = NSMutableIndexSet()
    dataTestType = context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequestForTestType, error: nil) as [TestType]

    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {

        context.deleteObject(dataTestType[indexPath.row] as NSManagedObject)
        context.save(nil)
        dataTestType.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

        if dataTestType.count == 0 {
            indexes.addIndex(indexPath.section)
        }

        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        tableView.deleteSections(indexes, withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Thank You very much!

Comment: Which line of code causes the crash, exactly?

Comment: this line inside of the commitEditingStyle function: context.deleteObject(dataTestType[indexPath.row] as NSManagedObject)

Comment: You do know that this is not how you delete with Core Data, right? You have to delete from the managed object context, save, and stop. You are then called back in NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate methods and that is where you update the UI.

Comment: try to make your call in this order:
context.deleteObject(dataTestType[indexPath.row] as NSManagedObject)
dataTestType.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

Answer (score 1):

You remove an object at `indexPath.row` from the `dataTestType` array

```
 dataTestType.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
```

And on the next line you try to get the object at the same index, but it won't exist if you deleted the only object in the array:

```
context.deleteObject(dataTestType[indexPath.row] as NSManagedObject)
```

You can simply solve the issue by reordering these two lines.

As matt pointed out, you can also use `NSFetchedResultsController`, as it is recommended for showing Core Data records in `UITableView`. Then you won't need `dataTestType` array at all. Now you call `context.executeFetchRequest` each time `commitEditingStyle` method is called. It is inefficient and can result in poor performance if you have many records to fetch.

Comment: Then i got another error. I will update my question!

Comment: This error means that after deleting the object you still return 1 from tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: method in your data source. Can we see this method's implementation as well? Also if you have many sections you may have to delete the section if it contains no rows, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1001239/2128900

Comment: Have you tried the solution proposed in my previous comment? Seems that you have delete the section when you delete the last row in that section.

Comment: Ok I tried it but there is a new error... I will update my post again.

Comment: You also have to change `numberOfSectionsInTableView` method so it returns the correct value after a section was deleted.

Comment: Ok it doesn't work but i don't want to delete the whole section. Just the cell has to be deleted by the user. The sections are fixed!

Comment: As I mentioned before, if you delete all the cells in a section, you have to delete this section (unless it is the only remaining section). Otherwise you will get crashes.