# Delete last row in section of UITableView without deleting section?

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch

Is there any way to delete the last row of a particular section in a UITableView without deleting that entire section? I would like to be able to remove the last row from a section but keep that section's header visible, as it indicates that the sections exists but has no data.

I've found multiple prior answers on StackOverflow, but their solutions all seem to be that you have to delete the section if you want to delete the last row of a section, e.g., [How to delete the last row of a section?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999908/how-to-delete-the-last-row-of-a-section)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...and it turns out that my error was elsewhere. In this case, I was accidentally trying to delete index path (1, 2147483647). This error resulted because I was assuming that the array I was using for that section's data contained the object I wanted to delete. Since it didn't, `[array indexOfObject:object]` equaled `2147483647`. Oddly enough, the error produced was `Invalid number of sections` rather than `Invalid number of rows in section`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your problem is related how UITableViewDataSource protocol works, if there isn't any content in the section, the section shouldn't be displayed.

But what you can do about it?

There is a simple way, in your dataSource numberOfRowsInSection you can do an if, that condition will verify if your dataSource count is equal to zero and return 1 instead, like this:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        var numberOfRows = 0
        switch section{
        case 0:
            numberOfRows = firstSectionArray.count()
        case 1:
            numberOfRows = secondSectionArray.count()

        default:
            ()
        }

        if numberOfRows == 0 {
            numberOfRows = 1
        }
        return numberOfRows
    }
```

And in the cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
         var numberOfRowsForThisSection = 0
         switch indexPath.section{
         case 0:
             numberOfRowsForThisSection = firstSectionArray.count()
         case 1:
             numberOfRowsForThisSection = secondSectionArray.count()

         default:
             ()
         }
         if numberOfRowsForThisSection == 0 {
             return tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("blankCell") as! UITableViewCell
         }

//        Do the default implementation
//        .
//        .
//        .

    }
```

"Oh, but now there is a white cell in the middle of the tableView"

Ok, let's break that:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        var numberOfRowsForThisSection = 0
        switch indexPath.section{
        case 0:
            numberOfRowsForThisSection = firstSectionArray.count()
        case 1:
            numberOfRowsForThisSection = secondSectionArray.count()

        default:
            ()
        }
        if numberOfRowsForThisSection == 0 {
            return 0.0
        }
    }
```